# Is there a way to restrict some users to access SQL tables based on their group

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2012, authorization

Please help me as I'm new to REST API, ASP.NET MVC and developing an application from scratch. I have a requirement from client to build a ASP.NET WEB API application with SQL Server database. I'm new to development so I need help on the queries raised by my client.

The application will have 3 groups of users: admin users, group 1 users and group 2 users. Since each of these groups will have different functionalities, the database tables are also going to be different for each group.

The query raised by my client is that group 1 users should not be able to access the tables of group 2 users and vice-versa even from outside the application.

I know at the application level, we can use an `[Authorize]` attribute in REST API calls so that access to each request is authenticated.

Apart from this, can we do anything at the database level so that users who know the database name, login will not be able to access 100's of SQL Server tables which they don't have to deal with by any other means. The connection string used in application will be having a login which will be using SQL Server authentication mode. Can multiple connection strings in my application be a solution to deal with this scenario?

Comment: *"users who know the database name, login"* - That seems like the source of the problem right there.  Don't give the users a database login that has access to things the users shouldn't be able to access.  If they need direct access to the database, create a login for them which has only the access they need.

Comment: @david ..thanks for the inputs. To elaborate on that point, I understand that users can connect to DB using excel or any other tools and for that they will have to use windows authentication with the corresponding login. But is there anything I need to do specifically for the login I'm going to use in the application to ensure security?

Comment: Sure... Don't share it with the users.  That's a pretty fundamental part of security, not giving users login credentials that they shouldn't have.